# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity which displays a DialogFragment, inside that dialog fragment I have  a linearlayout which contains one button, and a fragmentLAyout where I want to display the info.

I´d have to display one list of elements, and if any of them are pressed I´ll have to display the details for them. I thought the best way to do that is with fragments, when trying to call

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.framePlaceHolder, listAccountFragment).commit();
```

after creating my listAccountFragment, I´m getting this error

```
10-01 10:53:34.004  12836-12836/com.bbva.compassBuzz.qa.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bbva.compassBuzz.qa.debug, PID: 12836
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1.findViewById(Fragment.java:1746)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:943)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1836)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:993)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1384)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1179)
```

Comment: What's a fragmentLAyout? There's no such widget in the SDK. Please explain.

Comment: Does your Fragment have a view associated with it?

Comment: Could you post your fragment's onCreateView method?